# Google Maps image distorted (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been following [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/) on how to make a custom marker for Google maps, and I have got this part to work. However, I had to change some code in order to resize the image I am using on the marker.

This is the method I am using to do resize:

```
    private void UpdateMarkers(float zoom)
    {
        // Max zoom out => zoom = 3
        // Max zoom in  => zoom = 21
        int dimension = (int)zoom * 10;
        if (dimension == currentDimension)
            return;
        currentDimension = dimension;
        map.Clear();
        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            var immutableBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon);
            var mutableBitmap = immutableBitmap.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);
            mutableBitmap.Height = dimension;
            mutableBitmap.Width = dimension;
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(mutableBitmap);
            var img = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(mutableBitmap);

            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Pin.Address);
            marker.SetIcon(img);

            map.AddMarker(marker);
        }

    }
```

And here is a picture on how it looks:
[image: lol waht i tyep hrer]

In the original code, I would do something like this

```
var img = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.icon);
```

And this works. But I want to resize the image, so I found *a* way to do it, sort of.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a `Bitmap`, you can scale it via `Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap`:

```
var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon);
var scaledBitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, dimension, dimension, false);
var img = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

Note: Make sure you `Recycle` and `Dispose` your Bitmaps to avoid leaking memory.

Note BitmapFactory's `DecodeResource` and `CreateScaledBitmap` are heavy API calls, you might want to cache the results versus calling them over and over in your `foreach (var pin in customPins)` loop.

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm :) And thanks for the optimalization tip, will definitely do this!